# creating release-app for ios in react-native in normal system

Tags: ios, react-native, release

I'm owning linux system so is it possible to create release-apk for ios devices.

as when can create apk via using build command i.e (.gradlew bundleRelease)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release APK is only for Android Devices.  [How to release apk for android](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)

And for iOS the file type is **`.ipa`** and you need XCODE Tool for releasing purposes.

> A Mac is required to build projects with native code for iOS. You can
> follow the [Quick Start](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) to learn how to build your app using Expo
> instead.

As above mentioned you may need MacOS environment to build ios apps using XCODE.

Refer - https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/04/05/react-native-ios-app-store